# How to update a value in a dataframe by a specific condition, a specific colum and a specific row?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying update a value in this selector (in a loop):

```
 df.loc[df['wsid']==w,col_name].iloc[int(lag)]
```

Rebuild an example (inside the loop), will be:

```
 df.loc[df['wsid']==329,'stp_1'].iloc[0]
```

I can print the value, but I don't know how to update it:

```
df.loc[df['wsid']==329,'stp_1'].iloc[0] = 0  ??
```

Comment: did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept (tick on left), or ask more questions.

Comment: Hello @jpp. I tried your solution and doesn't work. I got this error: ----> 1 dfr.loc[dfr.loc[dfr['wsid']==329, 'stp_1'].iloc[0].index, 'stp_1'] = 1
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'index'. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
idx = df.loc[df['wsid']==w].index
df.loc[df.loc[idx, 'wsid'].index[0], 'wsid'] = 0
```

**Explanation**

- `.loc` accessor can be used to slice and set parts of a dataframe.
- It accepts inputs of the form `df.loc[index_labels, column_name]`. For more details, see [Selection by Label](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label).
- The index is extracted only for the subset of data you specify.

Comment: Change your answer to df.loc[df.loc[idx,col_name].index[int(i)],col_name] = 0 and I will accept.

Comment: First: idx = df.loc[df['wsid']==w].index and after this df.loc[df.loc[idx,col_name].index[int(i)],col_name] = np.nan solved for me.

Comment: I will wait for some hours to you change and accept your answer before posting what solve for my case! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you only want to update a certain cell in a dataframe based on some condition.

Here's the setup -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : np.arange(3, 13)})
df

   col
0    3
1    4
2    5
3    6
4    7
5    8
6    9
7   10
8   11
9   12
```

Now, assume you want to find records which are divisible by 3. However, you only want to update the first item that matches this condition. You can use `idxmax` in this case.

```
m = df.col.mod(3).eq(0)    
df.loc[m.idxmax(), 'col'] = 0
```

```
df

   col
0    0     # first item matching condition updated
1    4
2    5
3    6
4    7
5    8
6    9
7   10
8   11
9   12
```

On the other hand, if it is anything besides the first index, you'll need something a little more involved. For example, in the third row matching the condition.

```
i = 3
df.loc[m.mask(~m).dropna().index[i], 'col'] = 0

df

   col
0    3
1    4
2    5
3    6
4    7
5    8
6    9
7   10
8   11
9    0     # third item matching condition updated
```